# Notify when remote (RDP) user logs off?

Tags: remote-desktop, notifications

We have a number of computer's whose user's move between them at semi-random times. (Different tasks at different stations) Sometimes we want to remote into these computer's in order to perform some quick task that is necessary but not particularly time sensitive.

We could ask them to let us know when they log off, but they usually forget.

We are looking for is a way to be notified when the (RDP) user logs off.

Perhaps a way to check if anyone is logged into a PC remotely (every few minutes) and then send an email, or produce a messagebox or alike when that PC is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1. You can enable SNMP logging and have it send you a message when any user logs off.
2. You can audit the security logs (assuming it's Windows). If you do this, you can just pop open the event viewer before you RDP into their machine.
3. If you use any kind of deployment software (SCCP/Altiris/etc), they usually have the agents report back that information and it can be easily referenced.